# Pthread-ed filetransfer application crash

Tags: c++, network-programming, pthreads

I am developing a file transfer application and am using pthreads on the receiver side for receiving multiple files.

The function which is passed to pthreads calls the following function and at the end of this function I get a SIGABRT error and stack-smashing error appears on the terminal.
Please help me find the bugs. If you need anymore code I'd be able to post the same. Thanks in advance.

```
void recv_mesg(int new_sockid, char *fname)
{
    cout<<"New Thread created with "<<new_sockid<<" and "<<fname<<endl;
    char buf[MAXLINE];
    int fd;
    fd = open(fname, O_WRONLY );
    int len =0;
    while (len<1024)
    {
        int curr =  recv(new_sockid, buf, 1024-len, 0);
        //fprintf(stdout,"Message from Client:\n");
        len += curr;
        //write (fd, buf, curr);
        fputs(buf, stderr);

    }
    int file_size = 0;
    sscanf(buf,"%d",&file_size);
    if(file_size<=0)
        perror("File Size < 0");

    sprintf(buf,"Yes");
    send(new_sockid,buf,strlen(buf),0);
    len = 0;
    while (len<file_size)
    {
        int curr = recv(new_sockid, buf, min(file_size-len,MAXLINE), 0);
        len += curr;
        write (fd, buf, curr);
        //fputs(buf, stdout);
        //fflush(stdout);
    }
    len = 0;
    close(fd);
    close(new_sockid);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of MAXLINE?  If it's less than 1024, you're going to get stack smashing in your first while loop.

Comment: Also, you are not checking for errors or EOF in your recv() calls.  If the remote peer closes the TCP connection before all the data has been sent, your recv() calls will start returning 0 every time you call them, and that will cause either of your while loops to start spinning forever.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner and if recv() returns -1, it would funny too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. check the return code of system function, especially recv() which could return 0 or -1
2. you forgot to increment the buffer pointer you're givin to recv(), so each time it is called, the content of the buffer is overwritten
3. you forgot to ensure there's a NUL character at the end of buffer before calling sscanf()

Comment: I'll check that and get back to you. Thanks for your help :)